# BigCommerce API - Get Order Product By ID

Tags: php, api, curl, bigcommerce, php-curl

I am trying to get all Order Products of a given product_id within a collection of Orders using the following BigCommerce API call in PHP cURL:

[Get an Order Product](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#get-an-order-product)

```php
$pid = $_POST['product_id'];

$filter = array("status_id"=>11);

$orders = Bigcommerce::getOrders($filter);

foreach($orders as $order) {
    $oid = $order->id;
    $URL = $store_url . "/api/v2/orders/$oid/products/$pid.json";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); //Get status code

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = json_decode($response);

    echo "OID: " . $oid . " PID: " . $pid . " var_dump: ";
    print_r(var_dump($result) . "<br/>");
}
```

Output:

```
OID: 113948 PID: 4860 var_dump: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["status"]=> int(404) ["message"]=> string(37) "The requested resource was not found." } } 
OID: 113949 PID: 4860 var_dump: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#220 (2) { ["status"]=> int(404) ["message"]=> string(37) "The requested resource was not found." } } 
OID: 113954 PID: 4860 var_dump: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["status"]=> int(404) ["message"]=> string(37) "The requested resource was not found." } } 
OID: 113957 PID: 4860 var_dump: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#220 (2) { ["status"]=> int(404) ["message"]=> string(37) "The requested resource was not found." } }
```

At first, I thought maybe the Orders did not contain the product_id I was looking for so I added this code to the top of the loop:

```php
//Set $pid equal to the product_id of the first Order Product in the Order.
$pid = $order->products[0]->product_id;
```

New output:

```
OID: 113948 PID: 3703 var_dump: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["status"]=> int(404) ["message"]=> string(37) "The requested resource was not found." } } 
OID: 113949 PID: 3627 var_dump: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#220 (2) { ["status"]=> int(404) ["message"]=> string(37) "The requested resource was not found." } } 
OID: 113954 PID: 3816 var_dump: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#225 (2) { ["status"]=> int(404) ["message"]=> string(37) "The requested resource was not found." } } 
OID: 113957 PID: 3646 var_dump: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#222 (2) { ["status"]=> int(404) ["message"]=> string(37) "The requested resource was not found." } }
```

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible with the BigCommerce API, or do I have to iterate through all Order Products within the collection of Orders?

Comment: You need to iterate through each Order Products array returned from each individual Order. `foreach (orders as order) => foreach (order->products as product)`

Comment: In that case, my best bet would be to use async Node.js to make it more efficient? I considered maintaining orders of specific status_ids in a database and using BC webhooks with ngrok to add and remove records but I feel like that would be unnecessarily complex for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ha, yeah I was actually going to mention Node as you would be able to complete a task like this significantly faster _(for example: if 100 requests take 1 second each, a single-threaded php app would take 100 seconds to complete all 100 requests. However, a single-threaded Node.js app could complete all 100 requests in just **4 seconds** with 25 concurrent connections/requests-at-a-time)_ ........ since this is a PHP question, I could recommend that perhaps you take a multithreaded approach to achieve faster results.

Comment: I saw mention of Node in other BC related questions so I figured it could come into use. I haven't worked with Node before but I suppose this is as good of a reason as any to pick it up. There's a fair amount of code I've already written that could probably benefit from it as well. Thanks for the help/guidance!

Comment: I made a Node BC API Library that might help to quicken development. I did not however get a chance to include concurrency limit/queue. For example if you had an array of all your product IDs, and wanted to perform an API call while iterating through the product IDs, Node will open a connection for each ID until eventually the program will crash from too many connections opened. You'll want to use the Queue feature from the Async Library - https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue
The link to my BC API Connection file is here: https://github.com/mullinsr/bigcommerce-node.js
Hope it help

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look into that a bit further down the line. I ended up using async cURL with pthreads for the time being because I was already using Apache/PHP. Adding Node side-by-side with my current setup to functionally use it as an API by means of proxying requests through Apache to a _forever_ Node app became more convoluted than I had anticipated. EDIT: Your Node BC library looks interesting. I've bookmarked it for later :)

Comment: lol, u can get rid of apache entirely and direct requests directly to node as a web server / proxy. proxying from apache -> node is like having 4 slice of bread on sandwich.. 2 on top, 2 on bottom. why all the bread? lol. and u can do it all with a single thread *woooooh*, and then u can scale it by forking multiple processes from node to increase max socket/con count and even distribute processes to a specific core of your cpu (if multi core). this is how web should have operated from the start i feel... thus is the power of node. wait for v8 - it will cancel out past async control mechanisms

Comment: then with that model, u can even use it to act as a load balancer... distributing load equally to multiple servers each running multiple processes of node on each of its cpu cores. if a single node thread has been proven to handle 1 mill concurrent connections, then u can get the idea behind just how powerful this is for web apps and web concurrency